# Is there a way to dynamically link a color definition in CSS to another element's changing color?

Tags: html, css, animation, timing

I'm not sure how best to ask this question. I'm a novice, so apologies in advance if anything is clumsily put or painfully obvious, please be patient. I'll try to be as clear as possible. I'm developing a simple website with Bootstrap 4.3.1, Django 4.0.1, Python 3.9.5. I actually don't think any of that is relevant to this question, however, which is focused on my own stylesheet. On this site I have a logo that slowly changes color using the following css, which I adapted from 'Hue Loaders' (a loader UI I found on codepen.io - Thank you to Shivam Thaplival):

```
.loader {
  filter:hue-rotate(0deg);
  color:linear-gradient(45deg,#0f8,#08f);
  animation:hue infinite linear;
  animation-duration: 35s;
}

@keyframes hue{
  0%{filter: hue-rotate(0deg);}
  10%{filter: hue-rotate(30deg);}
  90%{filter: hue-rotate(330deg);}
  100%{filter: hue-rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Now I want the on-hover color for the other links on the navbar to be the same as the logo color, whatever it happens to be at that point. I tried applying the same code like so:

```
.font-nav:hover{
  filter:hue-rotate(0deg);
  color:linear-gradient(45deg,#0f8,#08f);
  animation:hue infinite linear;
  animation-duration: 35s;
}
```

The color change works, but the issue is that the animation starts whenever I start to hover, so the color's out of sync with the logo.
I'm wondering if I can somehow tie the timing of the hover animation to the logo animation. Any suggestions?

UPDATE: Figured out where I went wrong. Instead of adding the same class call for the animation that was already applied to my logo I copied the css to a different class. When I did that, it started the animation from the beginning when I hovered over links, but when the class call is the same, the animation is synched up across logo and hovered-over links. Here's the css I ended up with:

```
.font-nav{
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #333333;
}

.font-nav:hover{
  color: #ff9933;
}

#right-nb{
  text-align: right;
}

/* COLOR CHANGER BELOW */

.loader {
  filter:hue-rotate(0deg);
  color:linear-gradient(45deg,#0f8,#08f);
  animation:hue infinite linear;
  animation-duration: 35s;
}

@keyframes hue{
  0%{filter: hue-rotate(0deg);}
  10%{filter: hue-rotate(30deg);}
  90%{filter: hue-rotate(330deg);}
  100%{filter: hue-rotate(360deg);}
}
```

and the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    {% comment %} Bootstrap {% endcomment %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    {% comment %} Medium {% endcomment %}
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/medium-editor@latest/dist/js/medium-editor.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/medium-editor@latest/dist/css/medium-editor.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
    {% comment %} FontAwesome {% endcomment %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    {% comment %} Fonts {% endcomment %}
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    {% comment %} Custom CSS {% endcomment %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blogstyle.css' %}">
    
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="width: 40%;">
                <li></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link font-nav loader" href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link font-nav loader" href="https://www.github.com">Github</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link font-nav loader" href="https://www.linkedin.com">LinkedIn</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="logo" >
                <a class="navbar navbar-nav justify-content-center loader" style="width: 20%;" href="{% url 'post_list' %}"><img src="../../static/images/LASP_Logo_suppeq.png" alt="LASP Logo"></a>
            </div>
            <ul id="right-nb" class="nav navbar-nav justify-content-end" style="width: 40%;">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li><a class="nav-link font-nav loader" href="{% url 'post_new' %}">New Post</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link font-nav loader" href="{% url 'post_draft_list' %}">Drafts</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-link font-nav loader"a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a></li>
                    <li class="font-nav" style="font-size: 1em; color: #d3d3d3"><a>Logged in as: {{user.username }}</a></li>
                {% else %}
                    <li><a class="nav justify-content-end" href="{% url 'login' %}"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hello. can you put a snippet in your question? because it is very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The concept:

Use JavaScript to find the logo element.
Add an event listener for "animationstart"
Supply a handler function that will:
Find all the other elements that you want to animate
Add a class to these other elements that you want to animate
Provide the animation styling based on this class.

```
<style>
.loader {
    filter:hue-rotate(0deg);
    color:linear-gradient(45deg,#0f8,#08f);
    animation:hue infinite linear;
    animation-duration: 35s;
}

@keyframes hue{
    0% {filter: hue-rotate(0deg);}
    10% {filter: hue-rotate(30deg);}
    90% {filter: hue-rotate(330deg);}
    100% {filter: hue-rotate(360deg);}
}

.font-nav.anime {
    filter:hue-rotate(0deg);
    color:linear-gradient(45deg,#0f8,#08f);
    animation:hue infinite linear;
    animation-duration: 35s;
}
</style>

<script>
let logo = document.getElementById('logo');
logo.addEventListener("animationstart", function() {
    let links = document.querySelectorAll('.font-nav');
    let link;
    for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) { 
        link = links[i];
        link.classList.add('anime');
    }
}, false);
</script>

<body>
    <div id="logo"><img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=fcc0ea44ba27"</div>
    <a class="font-nav" href="#">A link</a>
    <a class="font-nav" href="#">Another link</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response Elaine! While I was trying to implement your solution I ended up stumbling on an easier way to implement it, which was just to apply to same "loader" class call to the font-nav's individually, rather than adding the animation to font-nav. Probably would've been obvious to you if I'd shared the html in the first place (sorry about that!). But thanks for the quick reply, it helped me get there! P.S. I'll share the html now so you'll see what I mean